# Meaning of "chase away" in "chase away a feeling"

Tags: meaning

> If someone or something **chases away** worries, fears, or other bad
>   feelings, they cause those feelings to change and become happier. (The
>   Collins English Dictionary)

Several examples I have found on the internet.

1. "Chase away the winter blues"

   https://www.dermatologytimes.com/article/chase-away-winter-blues
2. "Here are three great hiking destinations to chase that June Gloom away."  https://www.rei.com/blog/hike/how-to-beat-l-a-s-june-gloom

Perhaps I am overthinking. Does "chase away a feeling" mean make **the effects of** the feeling gone(the feeling is gone temporarily) or does it mean make the feeling **gone for good**(eradicate the feeling)?

For example, if a hike chases my June gloom away, will my gloom come back after I have finished the hike?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the thing being "chased" will probably eventually come back, but **not for a while**, maybe a day, maybe a week, maybe a month. But typically things like worries, fears, or bad feelings are pretty incessant and likely to return eventually.

So no, after you are done hiking the June Gloom would not immediately return, but it might the next weekend.